# Read value from a Table to another Table per automatic?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Its possible to read a value from one field to another field in SQL Server per automatic?

Like you can write `GETDATE()` at field "Default value and bindings" in SQL Server to get current date per automatic when you do a insert.

I want that a value copies from table A, row 1 to table B newly inserted row?

Comment: You can use a trigger or user defined function.  However, in most cases, this is best handled by using `JOIN`s on the tables.

Comment: This sounds a lot like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thank you! Trigger was the one i searched for!

Comment: The point that Gordon was making is that is rarely a good idea to copy data around in multiple tables. You almost always want one single point of truth. Meaning you store data once and only once. Then you join tables together to retrieve the values.